# Datepicker : Datepicker on Modal (z-index)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I face this problem today when I try to show datepicker on Bootstrap Modal.

I'm using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) as datepicker library.

Here is my modal form :

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Start Date</label>
          <div class="input-group date">
               <div class="input-group-addon">
                   <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
               </div>
               <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right datepicker" id="datepicker2" name="start_date">
           </div>
</div>
```

And here is my datepicker script :

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        zIndexOffset: 10000
    });
```

I already using zIndexOffset but it's not working, the calendar still shown behind the modal.

Can anyone suggest the solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the option `container`, adding the date picker inside the modal?

Comment: @visola not yet, where's the container option should i put ?

Comment: This is the option: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#container

Comment: i put in container but it's still not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try adding the date picker container inside the modal `div`. You could give the modal an `id` like this:

```
<div class="form-group" id="myModalWithDatePicker">
  <label for="start_date" class="control-label">Start Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right datepicker" id="datepicker2" name="start_date">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use the `container` option like the following:

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    container: '#myModalWithDatePicker',
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

Comment: @CodeOn, can you inspect the DOM to make sure the element is being put in the right place? I don't see any other reason why the date picker would not show inside the modal. I guess we need more details. If you could created a jsfiddle that reproduces this problem, would help a lot.

Comment: here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/88q5eacb/ 
so sorry the modal not came up, but it's working in my server.

Comment: @CodeOn, I used your jsfiddle to create one that works. It doesn't even need the `container` option. Maybe you can try to reproduce your issue in here: https://jsfiddle.net/88q5eacb/1/

Answer (score 1):

I used this option to fix.

```
.modal-open .ui-datepicker{z-index: 2000!important}
```

this option has been applied when modal open (class modal-open added to body)